# local char pointers inside a function

Tags: c, pointers, memory, malloc, free

I'm trying to code a function to filter non-alphabetic characters from a string in C.

So inside the function `wordFilter` I initialize a `char` array in order to store there the filtered string and then assign it to the pointer so I can return it.

However, it turns out that whenever the function is executed after the first time, it seems that the char array "reference" still keeps the value it when the last execution was done. Is there a way to make the "reference" array to be empty every time at the beginning of the execution of the function.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

char *wordFilter(char *string) {
    char reference[strlen(string)];
    int index = 0;
    while (*string) {
        if (isalpha(*string)) {
            reference[index] = *string;
            index++;
        }
        string++;
    }
    char *ptr = malloc(sizeof(char) * index);
    ptr = reference;
    return ptr;
}

int main() {
    char input[256];
    char *ptr = input;
    char input2[256];
    fgets(input, 256, stdin);
    
    char reference[256];
    for (int pos = 0; sscanf(ptr, "%s%n", input2, &pos) == 1; ptr += pos) {
        printf("%s ", wordFilter(input2));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are overwriting your newly allocated pointer `ptr` with a local array `reference`, which is ceasing to exist once the function is returning.

Comment: you can't return a pointer to a local array. The array becomes invalid when the function returns.

Comment: Anyway the allocation was one short for the missing nul terminator that should be written.

Comment: Did you think that `ptr = reference` would copy the contents of `reference` into the memory you allocated with `malloc()`?

Comment: Note that the C standard defines `sizeof(char)` to always equal to 1, so you don't need to multiply by that when invoking `malloc`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is this line: `ptr = reference;`  That doesn't copy the characters of `reference` into `ptr`.  As Eugene pointed out, that line causes the variable `ptr` to point to the stack-allocated `reference` array, leaking the memory you `malloc`ed.

Here are the changes I recommend:

1. Allocate `reference` like `char reference[strlen(string) + 1];` to allow room for the terminating null.
2. After the `while` loop, null-terminate `reference` like this: `reference[index] = '\0';`
3. Instead of using a `malloc` and copying the string, use `strdup(reference)` to heap-allocate a duplicate of `reference`, and then you can return what you get from `strdup`.

Comment: Or just `reference = malloc(strlen(string)+1)`? It wastes a little bit of dynamic memory, but I wouldn't consider that a big deal.

Comment: _Caveat_ to recommendation #3: `strdup` is originally a POSIX function, and traditionally non-standard, therefore not typically recommended. However, it appears that it has finally been adopted into the language standard as of C23. It's hard to believe that it took this long for something so fundamental and useful.

Answer (score 3):

The assignment `ptr = reference;` makes `ptr` point to the local array `reference` and overwrites the pointer to allocated memory, causing a *memory leak*, ie: the allocated block cannot be freed as its address is no available.

Returning `ptr` effectively returns a pointer to a local array that goes out of scope immediately, accessing it in the calling function has undefined behavior.

`char reference[strlen(string)];` is potentially too small for words entirely composed of letters: there is no space for the null terminator that is required for `prinf` to determine the end of the string.

Instead of allocating memory, you should pass a pointer to a destination array.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char *wordFilter(char *dest, const char *string) {
    size_t index = 0;
    while (*string) {
        if (isalpha((unsigned char)*string)) {
            dest[index] = *string;
            index++;
        }
        string++;
    }
    dest[index] = '\0';
    return dest;
}

int main(void) {
    char input[256];

    if (!fgets(input, 256, stdin))
        return 1;
    
    char buf1[256];
    char buf2[256];
    int pos;
    for (char *ptr = input; sscanf(ptr, "%s%n", buf1, &pos) == 1; ptr += pos) {
        printf("%s ", wordFilter(buf2, buf1));
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```